# How to avoid the potatoes from sticking to the pan while frying for french fries/finger chips?

Tags: potatoes, french-fries

Sometimes when I fry the potatoes for french fries, the potatoes stick to the pan which irritates me and I can't separate the potatoes because if I use the spoon a lot, it will cut the fries into pieces. Due to the scarcity of resources, I can't manage to buy a non-sticky pen. Kindly recommend me some solution.

Comment: Are you pan frying (in a frying pan), or deep frying (in several inches of oil)?

Comment: @elbrant - very good point. I'd never dreamed anyone would try to do chips/fries in a shallow pan... maybe I'm the only one, as the dupe it was closed against would seems to be more for 'bratkartoffeln' than 'chips'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some amount of salt in the pan while frying potatoes for french fries than your potatoes would not be sticky to the pan.
I use this easy trick and it's work for me

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you just aren't leaving sufficient room in the pan - you're crowding it.

When you drop food into the fryer, in the first few seconds there should be enough heat to seal the outside - this is **vital** for anything battered, but still important for such as fries.

If your heat drops too far because the pan is too crowded, this won't happen. To make matters worse, as it all sits in a lump trying to regain temperature, the starches in the potatoes start to set, gluing the individual fries together & also to the pan.

If finances won't allow a double-size pan - non-stick shouldn't be necessary for a deep-fryer - then try frying in two or even three batches instead, which will allow you to keep the heat up & the fries separate. If they hit each other & the sides less, they'll stick less. Stirring shouldn't be quite so necessary either, if they have enough room to move, one or two gentle swirls during the cook should be plenty.